# How to efficiently return an std::optional

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17, stdoptional

I would like to ask how to return an `std::optional` in an efficient way and I would like to use `std::make_optional()`.
For example lets have this code snippet:

```
std::optional<Path> CreateCanonicalPath(const std::string_view& path)
{
  std::error_code errorCode;
  const auto result = std::filesystem::weakly_canonical(std::filesystem::u8path(path), errorCode);
  return !errorCode ? std::make_optional(result) : std::nullopt;
}
```

I am particularly interested whether there is any optimization in passing `result` to `std::make_optional`. Would it be better to use `std::make_optional(std::move(result))`?

And does it prevent any RVO or NVRO?
The `result` is a local variable but it is not exactly in a return statement so I assume the compiler can't use move by itself.

Comment: Something related: https://youtu.be/dGCxMmGvocE?t=430

Comment: Did you create some measurements (benchmark tests)? Why do you think this is code which needs to be optimized? Is this a wild guess, or did you profiled your production code to spot bottle necks? From all of this `weakly_canonical` will be slowest part since it interacts with OS.

Comment: What is the point of wrapping `std::path` with `std::optional`? What is the difference between a returned empty `optional` and empty `path` in case of errors? AFAIK, `optional` is used mainly for types that themselves don't provide an "empty" state (such as integers), or where the empty state may be a valid result (such as with `std::string`).

Comment: @DanielLangr: An empty path is not necessary an invalid path. It is a valid result of path slicing, concatenating and normalizing, differentiating, etc. I don't think it necessary indicates an error. But I don't have much experience with `std::filesystem`.

Comment: @JiříLechner Me neither, but what you write makes sense.

Comment: Why do you want to use make_optional() ?  It kind off gets in the way.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, `make_optional()` is a factory pattern, it may allow to use some optimizations. For example `make_shared()` does it and it is kind of significant. I don't think it is the case for `make_optional()` but I like to have it consistent with other `make_...()` functions.

Comment: @JiříLechner   It may allow some optimization, but not in this case, since it would add a std::optional move assignment, and thus defeat return-in-place optimization.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's one obvious improvement:

```
std::optional<Path> CreateCanonicalPath(const std::string_view& path)
{
  std::error_code errorCode;
  auto result = std::filesystem::weakly_canonical(std::filesystem::u8path(path), errorCode);
  return !errorCode ? std::make_optional(std::move(result)) : std::nullopt;
}
```

Making the transitory object `const` will require employing copy-construction as part of instantiating the returned `std::optional`. This tweak should result in employing move semantics.

After this point, any further improvements would dependent highly on the compiler behavior. It's unlikely, but it's possible that, if benchmarked, some minor performance variances can be observed with alternate syntaxes, such as, for example:

```
std::optional<Path> CreateCanonicalPath(const std::string_view& path)
{
  std::error_code errorCode;
  auto result = std::make_optional(std::filesystem::weakly_canonical(std::filesystem::u8path(path), errorCode));

  if (errorCode)
     result.reset();

  return result;
}
```

If it's determined that the compiler will choose to elide the copy, as allowed by NVRO, then it's worth benchmarking this, as well. But only actual benchmarking will produce useful results.

Comment: So in the second snippet the move semantic will be used since the function returns local variable. And depending on the compiler even NVRO may be applied.